# How to obtain a certain expression as an expectation

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation

I have a probability space $(\Omega, M, \mathbb{P})$, where each $\omega \in \Omega$ is a random subset of natural numbers (i.e. This is a probability space of sequence of natural numbers sometimes used in probabilistic number theory. Even though it is referred to as sequences, it is actually subsets).

Suppose I have a collection of triplets of natural numbers $F$.
Denote $F(\omega) = \{ \theta = \{ n_1, n_2, n_3 \} \in F : \theta \subseteq \omega \}$.
In particular, for each $\omega \in \Omega$, $|F(\omega)|$ counts the number of triplets in $F$ that is a subset of $\omega$, and it is a random variable.

I know that the expectation is defined to be 
$$
\mathbb{E} (|F(\omega)|) = \int_{\Omega} |F(\omega)| d\mathbb{P}.
$$
Could someone please explain me why 
$$
\mathbb{E}(|F(\omega)|) = \sum_{\theta \in F} \mathbb{P}( \theta \subseteq \omega  )
$$
holds true? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. On the left hand side of your equation, you have $\mathbb{E}(|F(\omega)|)$, which is a **constant**. On the left hand side, you have a sum over $\theta \in F$. But this makes no sense. What would make sense would be $\theta \in F(\omega)$, but what should $\omega$ be? Finally, what do you mean by $\theta \subset \omega$, where $\omega$ is a sequence? Do you mean that $\theta$ is a subset of the range of $\omega$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Sorry for the confusion! Let me edit it.